# Change the "this" only for a specific function call

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, call

Let's say I have this code (that's an example, simplified):

```
// A Thing that expands other thing can use it's origin Thing's "init".
ThingThatExpands.super = function() {
    this.__originThing.init.apply(this, arguments);
}

// I make a Car Thing and give a color and a speed.
var Car = Thing("Toy Car", {
    init: function(color, speed) {
        this.color = color;
        this.speed = speed;
    }
});

// Then I make a Racing Car, which inherits the color and speed properties from it's origin
// (that's "Car", of course), but also has a cool sound!
var RacingCar = ThingThatExpands(Car, "Toy Police Car", {
    init: function() {
        this.super("#00F", 180);
        this.sound = "Wee-ooh! Wee-ooh!"
    }
})
```

Now, since "RacingCar" is a "child" of "Car", it has it's attributes and a nice "super" function that can be used to call "Car's" init.

Alright. The problem is: Since the "super" function gives the "child" Thing as the "this", it will change the "child" attributes, right? Ok, that's what we need.
But... It also means the "super" will be called from the "child" not the "origin" Thing, which shouldn't happen (and won't work).

Can I somehow "protect" the "this.super" call?

Comment: What is Thing? Is that from a library or should it be ThingThatExpands?

Comment: I think the sound should be `this.sound = "Vrooom! Vroooom!"` :)

Comment: That's some pseudo code, but I'm trying to fix a problem with my OOP lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the scope for a specific function, you must bind that function to the object of the desired scope.

So if you want `foo.bar()` to be called, but from the scope of `baz`, use `foo.bar.call(baz)` if you want the function to run right then, or use `foo.bar.bind(baz)` if you want it to use that scope when it is called in the app at run-time.

Comment: That's not really the problem.
See, I'm using `apply` at the `ThingThatExpands.super` function to change it's scope.
The problem is, by doing that, it also changes the `this.super` call's scope, which is what I don't want to happen.
Is there any way to check if there's a call to `super` happening and change the scope for that?

Comment: "Since the "super" function gives the "child" Thing as the "this", it will change the "child" attributes, right?" 

No. It will simply call the `init` method but from that object's scope. If you want to call that object's `init` method, just invoke it normally; it will automatically be bound to itself unless you say otherwise. All it is doing now is calling it's own init method from the scope of that object you're `apply`ing.

Comment: Look at the `init` on the `Car`, I'm changing the `this.color` and `this.speed` attributes. If I create a `Car` object, It will change it's `color` and `speed`, but if I create a `RacingCar`, the `this.super` should call the `Car.init` function and make it change It's (`RacingCar`) attributes. But that's not happening, because in the `this.super` call, since `this` is now equals `RacingCar`, it will call for itself over and over again (leading to a stack overflow).

Comment: Again -- no -- changing the function scope will simply run that same function from the scope you define. It will not look to see if the scoped object has a method of the same name to call. You might be confusing `bind`/`apply` with prototypal inheritance, if you are trying to inherit methods from other objects.